# Crystal Reports, Same report for every day in period

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2013

I have a report that can pull the number of reservations on a day. I have a report that I was able to create to give an average of the number of reservations per day for a given period.

Is there a way that I can create a master report and put the single-day reservations report into, so I can see one report for each day in a period without having to run the report multiple times?

For instance:
Inside the master report that has a parameter for a start date and an end date, I want to have a subreport for each day in that period so I can see the numbers from each day. I would also like to include a chart so I can visually show the changes.

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: You can create a group by day and break page after each page. Is it good enough?

Comment: What I am looking for is how to put a subreport with a parameter field "date" into a master report and select the month and it would give the subreport for all of the days in that month.